# Distinguish memory leak from memory fragmentation

Tags: memory-leaks, memory-fragmentation

I use linux command `top` to observe a program running and I can see increasing memory used by that program.

How to figure out that symptom is caused by memory leak or memory fragmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't do it using "top" command. The only way to detect memory leaks is by using special debugging tools called [memory debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger). One example is "Valgrind" but there are many of them.

Another consideration is what is the program language of the program. If it is some modern script language with garbage collector - the memory leaks are not possible at all (of course if the language interpreter/compiler is not buggy).

Mostly the compiled, relatively low level languages are prone to memory leaks - like C, C++, Pascal, Assembly and similar.

Comment: Well, the program language is C.

Comment: @Sayakiss - well, then a memory debugger is your tool. Note that most memory debuggers will run the program very slow, because they intercept all memory allocations/deallocations and even trace the program instruction by instruction in order to trace the pointers. Although I am not an expert in such programs.

Comment: @johnfound "If it is some modern script language with garbage collector - the memory leaks are not possible at all". Thats not quite right. Java and Python have garbage collector and you can easily cause memory leaks while coding in those languages.

Comment: @abc - I wrote "of course if the language interpreter/compiler is not buggy". If the GC allows memory leaks, it is by definition buggy and/or not properly implemented.

Comment: @johnfound You can cause memory leaks in your program even if the GC is not buggy. One e.g. You can pile up references to objects which are no longer needed or used.